# variable naming in a for loop in R

Tags: variables, naming

I'm new in programming and I faced the following issue in R
I've 332 database (csv files)

I want to store them in 332 data frames using a loop like this:

```
for (i in 1:332) {
paste("LOC",i,sep="") <- read.csv(if(i<10){paste("00",i,".csv",sep="")}
else if (i > 9 && i<100){paste("0",i,".csv",sep="")}
else {paste(i,".csv",sep="")})
```

When I run this the following error occurs
"target of assignment expands to non-language object"

How can I reach my goal?